# Server method not firing inside Listview LayoutTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, webforms

I have a server method that I want to run from a link inside the LayoutTemplate of my ListView. I've found that it doesn't fire unless I move the link outside the LayoutTemplate.  Is there any other way to run a Serverside event from an anchor or LinkButton inside of a LayoutTemplate? I thought about trying a link with a CommandName and capturing that inside of OnItemCommand but I don't know if that works inside of the LayoutTemplate.

My anchor inside the LayoutTemplate:

```
  <a runat="server" id="proceedCheckout"  OnServerClick="startCheckout">
```

The server method:

```
public void startCheckout(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {....
```

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to replicate your issue but with no luck. It seems to work for me. I have included my test mark-up and code so that you can see if you are missing something:

**Markup**

```
<asp:ListView ID="listView1" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="linkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton_Click" Text="Link Button"></asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
        <div runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div><%# Container.DataItem %></div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

**Code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> data = new List<string>();
    data.Add("Item 1");
    data.Add("Item 2");
    data.Add("Item 3");

    listView1.DataSource = data;
    listView1.DataBind();
}

protected void LinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
}
```

Hope this helps.